# Using large codebases with Jetbrains Webstorm 9

Tags: jvm, webstorm

I am working on a large webgl application, and I am using very large js files that contain all the information about a specific model. I keep getting out of memory errors in Webstorm and when I try to set the Xms higher, I get a JVM failed to start error. I reset it back to 512 mb, and now Webstorm will open, but it will immediately give me the "out of memory" error. Do I also need to set something with jvm?

Comment: I solved a similar issue by increasing the Xmx (the maximum allowed), not the Xms (the starting value). I think you should try the same

Comment: Install and use 64-bit Java ( https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under ) -- if on Windows, you will have to use `WebStorm64.exe` instead of `WebStorm.exe`.

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Appearance & Behaviour/Appearance**, and set the checkbox **"Show Memory Indicator"**

A memory indicator will appear on the bottom left side of the screen

[image]

Here's the nice thing: If you click on it, you do a garbage collection of the currently used memory. It is a good practice to deplete the used memory once it's close to the limit. This is a common practice and has saved me of crashes many times.